# Detecting sampling instant for a discerete controller in MATLAB/Simulink

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink, sampling, mpc

Let us assume that I have a continuous system in Simulink to be controlled. First,  I apply a Kalman filter to estimate the states of the system.
In the next stage, I will use the estimated state (`x_hat`) in an embedded MATLAB function which calls a model predictive controller function `my_mpc` like so:

```
function [u]= emd_fcn(x_hat , r,  t,  Ts)  

      % x_hat:  estimated state,  r: reference to be tracked, 
      t: clock time,   Ts: sampling  period

      %#codegen
      coder.extrinsic('my_mpc');  % to call the function my_mpc 

       ----- % some initialization code

      if mod(t, Ts)==0

            u=my_mpc(x, r)

      else
            u=-----; % some code.

      end


end
```

However, since the clock time `t` is a variable, `mod(t, Ts) == 0` will not be the case.
My question is: how can we detect the sampling instant to apply the discrete mpc control input to the continuous system?

Answer (score 0):

You should just make the controller discrete.  Right click on the MATLAB Function block, select Block Parameters, and specify a discrete sample time.